# Reveal animation for text stopped working with horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview, splitting.js

My headline and text animations stopped working when they come into view. I am using both Splitting.js and ScrollOut.js. It all worked fine until I added some CSS to make the design horizontal instead of vertical.

I know that the animations work, but it seems like it cannot read when the new text are coming into view anymore, because of the horizontal CSS. How do I fix this?

Would it be better to switch to some jQuery for the horizontal layout instead of CSS?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a link to my current demo: https://mschristensen.com/demosites/new2/index.html

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(event){

// Headline + text animation
Splitting();

// Headline + text trigger on scroll
ScrollOut({
    targets: '[data-splitting]',
    scrollingElement: ".inner-wrapper"
});
```

});

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <!-- SETTINGS -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">

    <!-- Favicon -->

    <!-- PAGE INFO -->
    <title>M. S. Christensen</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Morten Stig Christensen">
    <meta name="description" content="Hello! I am a digital/visual designer from Copenhagen, Denmark. With a background in frontend design and development, my primary strength is within website and app design.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Danish digital designer, Digital Designer, Visual designer, Danish visual designer, Dansk designer, Designer, Digital designer, Freelance digital designer, Freelance, Freelance designer, HTML, HTML5, CSS, CSS3, PhotoShop, Illustrator, InDesign, Copenhagen, Denmark, Designer, SASS, CSS / CSS3, UI, UX, User Interface, Usability Experience, WordPress, Responsive Design, jQuery, Morten, Morten Stig Christensen, Morten Christensen, MSChristensen, Creative, Creative designer, Kreativ designer, Kreativ">

    <!-- Styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting-cells.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer-wrapper">
        <div class="inner-wrapper">
            <section class="page-introduction">
                <div>
                    <h1 data-splitting="lines">Creative, experienced, and user-centric. Let me elaborate...</h1>
                    <p data-splitting="">Hello, my name is Morten. I am an ambitious and passionate designer with 7+ years of experience. Currently living in Copenhagen, Denmark, but looking for a full time position in Tokyo, Japan.</p>
                    <nav class="buttons">
                        <a class="button primary">My work</a>
                        <a class="button secondary">Get in touch</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="page-introduction">
                <div>
                    <h1 data-splitting="lines">Creative, experienced, and user-centric. Let me elaborate...</h1>
                    <p data-splitting="">Hello, my name is Morten. I am an ambitious and passionate designer with 7+ years of experience. Currently living in Copenhagen, Denmark, but looking for a full time position in Tokyo, Japan.</p>
                    <nav class="buttons">
                        <a class="button primary">My work</a>
                        <a class="button secondary">Get in touch</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="page-introduction">
                <div>
                    <h1 data-splitting="lines">Creative, experienced, and user-centric. Let me elaborate...</h1>
                    <p data-splitting="">Hello, my name is Morten. I am an ambitious and passionate designer with 7+ years of experience. Currently living in Copenhagen, Denmark, but looking for a full time position in Tokyo, Japan.</p>
                    <nav class="buttons">
                        <a class="button primary">My work</a>
                        <a class="button secondary">Get in touch</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="page-introduction">
                <div>
                    <h1 data-splitting="lines">Creative, experienced, and user-centric. Let me elaborate...</h1>
                    <p data-splitting="">Hello, my name is Morten. I am an ambitious and passionate designer with 7+ years of experience. Currently living in Copenhagen, Denmark, but looking for a full time position in Tokyo, Japan.</p>
                    <nav class="buttons">
                        <a class="button primary">My work</a>
                        <a class="button secondary">Get in touch</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazy/1.7.4/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/scroll-out/dist/scroll-out.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var console = { log: function() {} };
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100;300;500;900");

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-size: 3.125rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

h4, h5, h6 {
  font-size: 0.625rem;
}

h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1.2;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #555555;
}

a {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #555555;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0.63, 0.5, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0.63, 0.5, 0.99);
}

a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.button.primary {
  background-color: #F8BC49;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.button.primary:hover {
  background-color: #EBB245;
}

.button.secondary {
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.button.secondary:hover {
  border-color: #cccccc;
}

h1 .word, h2 .word, h3 .word, h4 .word, h5 .word, h6 .word {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

h1 .word::after, h2 .word::after, h3 .word::after, h4 .word::after, h5 .word::after, h6 .word::after {
  content: attr(data-word);
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0.63, 0.5, 0.99);
  transition-delay: calc(.2s * var(--line-index));
}

h1[data-scroll="in"] .word::after, h2[data-scroll="in"] .word::after, h3[data-scroll="in"] .word::after, h4[data-scroll="in"] .word::after, h5[data-scroll="in"] .word::after, h6[data-scroll="in"] .word::after {
  transform: translateY(0%);
  visibility: visible;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p .char {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0.63, 0.5, 0.99);
  transition-delay: calc(2.5ms * var(--char-index) + 500ms );
}

p[data-scroll="in"] .char {
  transform: translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.page-introduction {
  width: 60vw;
  position: relative;
}

.page-introduction div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.page-introduction div h1 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.page-introduction div p {
  width: 75%;
}

.page-introduction div nav {
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: table;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Noto Sans JP", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 100;
}

html:focus,
body:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.outer-wrapper .inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 400vw;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.outer-wrapper .inner-wrapper section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  max-width: 1710px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Do anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can anybody help me? :S